# How can I add the values from the list to other list for each row?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list (called `lines`) with 700 Values, and each line looks like this: `1, 370, 351`, the next row is 
`2, 325, 515` etc.

```py
l = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    a = lines[i].split(',')
    for k in a:
        j = k.replace(' ','')
        l.append(j)
```

I use this for loop to split first the commas, and then to replace the big space on the first number ('    1).

At the End I become a list with size 2100, but I want to have the 3 values ​​in each line of the list.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are expecting ? I don't really follow what the final output should be.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of lists as ouput. I.e. a list where every element is a list of length of the numbers in a?

You would do it like this:

```py
l = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    a = lines[i].split(',')
    sublist = []
    for k in a:
        j = k.replace(' ','')
        sublist.append(j)
        l.append(sublist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list like this:

`lines = ["1, 370, 351", "2, 325, 515"]`

you could try something like this:

```
new_list = []
for line in lines:
    line_array = line.split(",")
    if len(line_array) == 3:
        new_list.append(line_array)
    else:
        print("This line does not have 3 values (not taking it into account):", line)
```

And if you want to check it:

```
for a, b, c in new_list:
    print(a, b, c)
```

And you should get:

```
1  370  351
2  325  515
```